# How to set CLI flags for Google Chrome?

Tags: unity, command-line, google-chrome

Where can I set CLI flags for Google Chrome on Unity?

Comment: Do you mean how to set command line options for Chrome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.desktop` or `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` for the following line:

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U
```

Add the flag you need in there, save it, then run Chrome again and pin it to your launcher, that should do the trick.

Comment: ...just until the next upgrade overwrites it :(

Comment: I’m still looking for a permanent solution to this.

Comment: Install `menulibre` as a way to get to the "launcher".

Answer (score 3):

A way is to set flags in the environment variable `CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS`:

```
export CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS="insert_content_here"
```

Comment: This could be flagged as low quality. It will better if you can add a reference for this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: `CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS` seems to have no effect on Chrome 46.

Comment: Confirmed this still works as of Chromium 52.0, however, it is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

For xubuntu/xfce4, though it might work similarly elsewhere:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

and modify the three `Exec=` lines in `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` to include the arguments you want.  Because it has the same filename, xfce4-whiskermenu will pick up only your modified `google-chrome.desktop`.

If Chrome is your default browser, another application opening a URL will still cause Chrome to launch without your arguments.  To fix this, create a new file `~/bin/google-chrome` with these contents:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome YOUR_EXTRA_ARGS "$@"
```

and `chmod +x ~/bin/google-chrome`.  Then, in Preferred Applications, set your Web Browser to Other... and enter:

```
/home/YOUR_USERNAME/bin/google-chrome "%s"
```

Also, to avoid having to change the arguments in four places in the future, you can point the `Exec=` lines in `google-chrome.desktop` to your `/home/YOUR_USERNAME/bin/google-chrome`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Xubuntu and I was trying to figure this one out as well. I tried the solution to edit the .desktop file. I haven't updated, but I have the same concern as you (will it get overwritten). I tried a different option where I added an alias to my .bashrc file.

```
alias chromium-browser="/usr/bin/chromium-browser [FLAGS]"
```

Answer (score 2):

For chromium, you can create a script in `/etc/chromium-browser/customizations`

For instance i have a script with one line

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="${CHROMIUM_FLAGS} --enable_hidpi=1 --process-per-site"
```

I imagine chrome has something similar.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It persists between package updates and doesn't involve any desktop file hackery.

Answer (score 2):

For Chromium, the method suggested by @errr is correct, however, it is deprecated as of Chromium 52 (or earlier):

```
┌ alex [~]
└──> export CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS="--version"
┌ alex [~]
└──> chromium-browser
Using PPAPI flash.
WARNING: $CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS is deprecated. Instead, update   CHROMIUM_FLAGS in ~/.chromium-browser.init or place configuration for all sers in /etc/chromium-browser/customizations/ .
WARNING: Ignoring system flags because $CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS is set.
CHROMIUM_FLAGS= --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=
CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS=--version
Chromium 52.0.2743.116 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04
```

As you can see, the solution is quite obvious however.

```
┌ alex [~]
└──> echo "CHROMIUM_FLAGS=\"--version\"" >> ~/.chromium-browser.init
chromium-browser
┌ alex [~]
└──> chromium
Using PPAPI flash.
Chromium 52.0.2743.116 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04
```

These changes will **persist** through upgrades, making it superior to solutions updating system files.

However, for Google Chrome, I have not found a single way other than modifying desktop files or writing custom launchers.

Answer (score 1):

First, open up a terminal. Then type in `google-chrome-(release-type) -(flag)`
Replace `(release-type)` with the release of google chrome you are using (stable,unstable,ect.) and `(flag)` with the flag that you want to run Google Chrome with.

To have the flags run when you click on the Google Chrome Unity icon in the launcher:

- first install Unity Launcher Editor.
- Open up a terminal window and type `sudo apt-get install bzr`.
- When it is has finished installing, type `bzr branch lp:unity-launcher-editor`.
- Next, launch Unity Launcher Editor by typing `~/unity-launcher-editor/unitylaunchereditor/main.py`.
- Now, click on the Google Chrome icon, and add the flag you want to run in the Command box.

Comment: I want the flag to be used every time I open Google Chrome from launcher.

Comment: Isn't there just a .desktop file somewhere that I can edit?

Comment: I am not currently aware of a .desktop file you can edit. I would suggest you use Unity Launcher Editor as explained above to add CLI flags to the Google Chrome Launcher icon.

Comment: some problem with the project, answer need to be updated

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`
2. Add the desired flags to the `Exec` line
3. Run `sudo chattr +a /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` to prevent your change from being overwritten on update.

Comment: This makes dpkg error out on upgrades of Chrome.  `unable to make backup link of './usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop' before installing new version: Operation not permitted`  followed by `dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)`

Comment: Run `sudo chattr -a /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` then do the dpkg update, then re-do the steps above.